# Why can't I concatenate items in this list but I can multiply them?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list that encases the items within apostrophes and I can use the following 'for loop'

```
list1 = ['1','2','3']
list2 = [i * 5 for i in list1]
print list2
```

which appears to treat the list items as numbers, yet when I change the multiply sign to an add sign:

```
list1 = ['1','2','3']
list2 = [i + 5 for i in list1]
print list2
```

I get the error "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects". If the list items were strings, I shouldn't be able to multiply them. Since I can they must be numbers, so in that case why can't I add anything to them?

EDIT: Can someone please tell me why this question is bad? I have read through the posting rules but am about to be kicked because I am getting a lot of negative feedback but I am just a beginner and am trying to write as best as I can.

Comment: When you print list2, it should come out like this: `['11111', '22222', '33333']`. Multiplication just replicates the string, so it's not treating it like an int.

Comment: in python you can multply a string to repeat it muliple times

Comment: Ah okay, thank you

Comment: re: "why is the question bad?" You've made your examples overly complicated... there is a random `number = 0` in both, and you're dealing with lists without breaking the problem down. You've also not examined your output very closely, otherwise you'd see that `'1' * 5` is not `5`.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I have been working on a large chunk of code for many hours now and was just concentrating on the error codes instead of doing the maths and realising it wasn't actually computing what I thought it was.

Comment: @Davy I don't disagree, but the best way to understand a problem is to break it down into it's component parts... Their approach with lists hasn't worked, so the next step would be to ditch the lists. I'm not accusing them (sorry if it came across that way), rather trying to show a method that can be used to solve a plethora of problems, and trying to give an answer as to why people would view it as a 'poor' question.

Comment: It's not "bad" per se, but the fact that you asked this question and included incorrect assumptions asserted as actual observations of the function results (*appears to treat the list items as numbers*) demonstrates that you haven't spent 30 seconds to execute these 3 lines of code in a console. Had you done that, your question would be a very different one and you likely would've found out why the operators work in such a way on text sequences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first example **you do not multiply numerically**: if you **multiply a string**, you **repeat the string** `n` times, like:

```
>>> "foo"*5
'foofoofoofoofoo'
```

So your first code fragment results in:

```
>>> [i * 5 for i in list1] # see, you repeat the string
['11111', '22222', '33333']
```

There is *no support* for addition between `str`ings and `int`s, so that will error. Probably because the only reasonable operation would be to add the number to the end of the string, but that is again not *numerical* addition.

If you want to do **numerical calculations**, you have to convert it to an `int` first with `int(..)`:

```
>>> [int(i) * 5 for i in list1]
[5, 10, 15]
>>> [int(i) + 5 for i in list1]
[6, 7, 8]
```

As you can see the result here is a list with `int`s (there are not quotation marks around the numbers).

Most sequences (lists, tuples, strings, etc.) will construct the same type of sequence with repetition when you multiply them with an integer. Like:

```
>>> [1,'a',2,"five"]*3
[1, 'a', 2, 'five', 1, 'a', 2, 'five', 1, 'a', 2, 'five']
>>> (1,'a',2,"five")*3
(1, 'a', 2, 'five', 1, 'a', 2, 'five', 1, 'a', 2, 'five')
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this on the command line:

```py
>>> '1' * 5
'11111'
>>> '1' + 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Is that what you expected? Probably not...

---

If you want to do calculations, then you will need to do the following:

```py
>>> int('1') * 5
5
>>> int('1') + 5
6
```

These both result in `int`s, not `str`s.

---

If you want to do string concatenation, then you will need to do one of the following:

```py
>>> '1' + '5'
'15'
>>> '1' + str(5)
'15'
```

Answer (score 3):

`'2' * 5` would return '22222' as string and not 10 as you would think.

You should cast your variable `int(i) + 5`, this would consider the i as integer instead of string.

Answer (score 2):

`'1' * 5` will give you `'11111'`, and not `5`.
You can multiply a string and an integer. However, you can't add a string and an integer.